# Rails 3 ActiveRecord update not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Have a problem with updating an existing record of my DB.

In my view I have check-box. When user clicks on it the ajax call triggers.
In my controller a have such code:

```
t = Materialtitle.find(@doc_code)
t.pub_template = params[:checked]
t.save!
```

**Problem: when I first time click on check-box everything is updated. But when I second time click it is no updated.** And in log I have empty transaction:

```
←[1m←[35mMaterialtitle Load (0.0ms)←[0m  SELECT TOP (1) [materialtitles].* FRO
[materialtitles] WHERE [materialtitles].[id] = 181
←[1m←[36mEXECUTE (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mBEGIN TRANSACTION←[0m
←[1m←[35mEXECUTE (0.0ms)←[0m  COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: What's in the `params` the second time?

Comment: First time url - **http://127.0.0.1:3000/admin/templates/74/publicate?locale=uk&checked=1**, second time - **http://127.0.0.1:3000/admin/templates/74/publicate?locale=uk&checked=0**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In these situations where I need to change the state of a model's attribute from true to false and viceversa with an ajax call fired with a user-actionable checkbox, I've found the easiest way to do it is with **toggle!**

In your case, replace the following two lines in the controller's code:

```
t.pub_template = params[:checked]
t.save!
```

With the following one, and it will just work:

```
t.toggle!(:pub_template)
```

Just make sure when loading the view that you're showing the right, actual state of the model's attribute so the user don't get confused.

I hope you find this useful.